# Concatenate values from row to array Excel

Tags: excel

I have some data in excel that need to be translated from duplicated rows to array in 1 row, im was trying Find > Go to special, Replace Blanks by Value, but the rows are not equals.

Example of Excel data:

```
Code    Image
112001  image1.jpg
112001  image2.jpg
112001  image3.jpg

112004  image1.jpg
112004  image2jpg

554551  image1.jpg
554551  image2.jpg
554551  image3.jpg
554551  image4.jpg
```

The rusult need to be

```
Code    Image
112001  image1.jpg  image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg
112001  image2.jpg
112001  image3.jpg

112004  image1.jpg  image1.jpg,image2.jpg
112004  image2jpg

554551  image1.jpg  image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image4.jpg
554551  image2.jpg
554551  image3.jpg
554551  image4.jpg
```

The issue is that i have 7.000 Rows and need to be programatically.

Some suggestion to do the array are very welcome.

Comment: is column a always sorted?

Comment: Hi, colum a is as it, can be sorted, but all codes are sorted by groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play with a small set of data, and came up with the below bit of code.

```
Sub CompareAndOutput()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim row As Long, col As Long, recordCount As Long

    Dim output As String
    Dim chkStr As String, prevStr As String

    On Error GoTo err

    'set sheet we want to use
    Set ws = Sheet1

    'set check column to A
    col = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual



    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row

        'loop through rows
        For row = 1 To lastRow + 1

            'set column A string to compare
            chkStr = ws.Cells(row, col).Value

            'compare string to previous value
            If chkStr <> prevStr Then

            'output string at bottom of group
            ws.Cells(row - recordCount, 3).Value = output

            'clear values
            output = ""
            recordCount = 0
            End If

            'build output string
            output = output & " " & ws.Cells(row, 2).Value

            recordCount = recordCount + 1

            'set previous string for comparison next loop
            prevStr = chkStr

        Next row


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Exit Sub
err:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "An error occured"

End Sub
```

it loops through the rows and outputs at the top of the group... Column A groups must be together for it to work though..